# Vector Space Basis' Proof

Tags: vector-spaces

Show that : if $B=\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and $A= \{ Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_p\}$ are basis' of a vector space $(E, +, \cdot)$ that means $n=p$.

I have no idea on how to start this proof, if I can get some help that would be much appreciated.

$PS$ : *Sorry for the way the question is translated because I had to translate it from Arabic to English and I don't know the right words to use and don't know how to use latex, and the '$X$s" and '$Y$s" are vectors.*

**Thanks to anyone who has any suggestions.**

Comment: use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma

Comment: This is the [Dimension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).